# How to debug DOM exceptions in Webkit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem with DOM exceptions in Google Chrome as well as in all other Webkit based browsers. I'm working on a Google Maps based [data stream browser](http://toozla.com/toozla/streams/browse/), and in these browsers it freezes the map after several zoom-ins and zoom-outs.

It throws an `INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1` with a rather unintelligible stack trace. And what's even worse, when I try to use the inspector to pause on exceptions, the tab crashes.

I've tried it in Google Chrome, in Chromium and in Midori, all three give the same result.

I would appreciate any input on how to trace this problem, or on what can possibly be causing it.

Just one last thought - the problem has appeared after Google had rolled out it's API v.3.4. Until recently I have been able to suppress this problem by using the 3.3 version, but now that it has been retired, I have no choice but to face it.

Comment: Happening in Chrome stable but not in Canary. I know this error happens when you divide by zero

Answer (score 1):

Open up Chrome DevTools (Ctrl-Shift-I on Windows/Linux), switch to the Scripts tab and click the "Pause" button in the status bar (tri-state) until its tooltip shows "Pause on uncaught exceptions", then activate the failing code.

Comment: The problem was that Chrome crashed when I did this. But now it doesn't, maybe because it has been updated and the problem can now be debugged.
So the whole question is now meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX_SIZE_ERR` can happen when accessing a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays), like an Int8Array or something, outside of its bounds. Are you doing that anywhere?

Comment: Not explicitly, but maybe it is done somewhere inside Google Maps' scripts, I will have to check, thanks!